# flask form server side generation based on array

Tags: flask, jinja2, flask-wtforms

I am trying to create a site that will have a lot of different forms. The forms will be mostly the same, they will just each have a few extra different variables that the user has to input, i.e. they all have name, description, and file fields, but each one has a few different extra fields. I want to know if there is a way to dynamically generate these fields from a single form in flask. For example

```
    from flask_wtf import FlaskForm
    from wtforms import StringField, FileField, TextField, SubmitField
    
    class dataEntryForm(FlaskForm, variables):
        name = StringField('Name', [DataRequired()])
        description = TextField('Description')


        for variable in variables:
            #generate a field with the name variable


        uploadFile = FileField('File', [DataRequired()])
        submit = SubmitField('Enter Job')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if i understand your concern, you can define a base class `UserForm` for e.g that holds the common fields and then extend its attributes with `Mixins` (read more [here](https://www.ianlewis.org/en/mixins-and-python)). Based on your logic you can define many `Mixins` as needed:

```
class UserForm(DateStampsFormMixin, SocialAccountsFormMixin, FlaskForm):
    name = StringField('Name', [DataRequired()])
    description = TextField('Description')
    uploadFile = FileField('File', [DataRequired()])
    submit = SubmitField('Enter Job')
```

and below the 2 `Mixins` :

```
class SocialAccountsFormMixin(FlaskForm):
    website_url = StringField('website url', [..])
    twitter_url = StringField('twitter url', [..])
    github_url = StringField('github url', [..])
    [..]
```

and

```
class DateStampsFormMixin(FlaskForm):
    created_at = DateTimeField('Created at', [..])
    updated_at = DateTimeField('Updated at', [..])
```

Comment: Ok, so I think that might work for my problem, thanks! If I also wanted to be able to define the `Mixins` it in the route function, is there a way to do that too?

Comment: glade that solves your issue. i recommend you opening a new question with some code even pseudo code like you do in this question and i'll be able to help you. Don't forget to give my answer the green tick :)

Comment: In the example you showed, the `Mixins` inherit from a class `object`, should this be FlaskForm?